# Browse for file and return filepath (from web browser)

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

First off, I'm fairly new to the webpage creation deal, but I have done a decent amount of research.

What I am looking for is a way to browse for a file, then collect its path as a variable, from an HTML page. This will be a client-side Excel file, which will then run a macro and return a result.

I realize that what I am trying to do is usually not possible (or at least not recommended), however the tool I am working on has very limited and controlled use (I can specify the environment, including which browser, browser version, operating system, and pretty much anything else).

Knowing this, I have the second half working: I'm using a roundabout method of Firefox, the IE Tab extension, and ActiveX to open and run the Excel macro successfully. Right now though, I specify the Excel file's path; I'd like to give the user the option to choose the file. Is there a way to do this (I'm guessing in ActiveX)?

A bonus would be specifying the starting directory for the browse dialog box.

**EDIT:**

Some progress (I think) - I've added the following to my Javascript and get a "Type mismatch" error testing in IE9. I think it may have something to do with the quoting of "msoFileDialogFilePicker", but removing the quotes makes Javascript think it's a variable.

`Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");`
`Excel.FileDialog("msoFileDialogFilePicker").Show`

However, this file picker seems to be exactly what I want.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.getopenfilename.aspx) solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Application.GetOpenFilename works. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.getopenfilename.aspx).